# How to configure Apache to serve default Index.html file stored on attached AWS EBS volume?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, apache-2.4, amazon-ebs

I have a AWS EC2 Linux VM with Apache installed, and my requirement to configure Apache so that the default Index.html file served is the one from the attached EBS volume (where I have already stored it), instead of from the default /var/www/html directory configured as DocumentRoot in Apache. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Modify the httpd.conf file.

Comment: Thanks! But what exactly to modify in httpd.conf?

Comment: That depends on its current contents. Read it and work it out. This is very basic stuff and you're going to have to understand what it does to run an Apache server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases httpd.conf is located in /etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
You need to change the DocumentRoot setting in your httpd.conf file. 
More information here:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/3/html/Reference_Guide/s1-apache-config.html

You should see something like

`<Directory "/var/www/html">` - change it to

`<Directory "/mountedEBS/desiredfolder">`

In order to apply changes, don't forget to restart your Apache.